# Realizar split con SPACE en elementos encapsulados por ""

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, uipath

¡Hola buen día!, mi pregunta es la siguiente, tengo un string que básicamente es la lectura de un XML el cual contiene atributos encapsulados por "", mi objetivo es poder obtener todos estos atributos para después insertarlos en una base de datos pero no logro realizar el split sin que los elementos que estan entre comillas también se vean separados, por ejemplo

```
String() x = "Nombre=""Bryann Luna García"" LugarTrabajo=""Por ahí"""
x.Split(Chr(32))
```

Esto me devuelve:

```
Nombre="Bryann
Luna
Garcia"
LugarTrabajo="Por
Ahí"
```

Y lo que quiero obtener es

```
Nombre="Bryann Luna García"
LugarTrabajo="Por ahí"
```

How can i do that? Saludos!

P.D Esto lo realizo en Vb.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bastaría con hacer [`Split`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.string.split?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(System.String.Split);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8) por el caracter `"` escapándolo correctamente.

**Snippet C#**

```
string cadenaOriginal = @"Nombre=""Bryann Luna García"" LugarTrabajo=""Por ahí""";
//Hago split por el caracter "
var result = cadenaOriginal.Split("\"");    
Console.WriteLine(result[0].Trim()); //Nombre=
Console.WriteLine(result[1].Trim()); //Bryann Luna García
Console.WriteLine(result[2].Trim()); //LugarTrabajo=
Console.WriteLine(result[3].Trim()); //Por ahí
```

[Demo online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/T0sdB9)

**Snippet VB**

```
Dim cadenaOriginal = "Nombre=""Bryann Luna García"" LugarTrabajo=""Por ahí"""
Dim result = cadenaOriginal.Split("""")
Console.WriteLine(result(0).Trim)
Console.WriteLine(result(1).Trim)
Console.WriteLine(result(2).Trim)
Console.WriteLine(result(3).Trim)
```

Comment: La idea esta genial y funciona correctamente, pero separaría la variable y su declaración en 2, genera 4 lineas y busco obtener en este caso en específico 2, que el separador si sea un SPACE (Chr(32)) pero si esta encapsulado por "" se respete como una sola linea, saludos!

Comment: @BryannLuna si te soy completamente sincero, no entiendo que quieres hacer